# docker-compose: есть собственный DNS в контейнере, как его назначить в качестве DNS для соседних сервисов

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Итак, есть собственный DNS резолвер (unbound) в контейнере, для резолвинга публичных доменов.

Как его назначить в качестве DNS для соседних сервисов, например для Exim?

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  exim:
    build: ./exim
    depends_on:
      - dns
    dns:
      # вот тут ожидается IP адрес, но как его получить?
      - dns
  dns:
    build: ./dns
```

По идее, в `services.exim.dns` нужно указать список IP адресов, но этот адрес заранее не известен, есть только название сервиса `dns`.

Answer (score 0):

Пока что остановился на таком варианте: в запускаемом контейнере выполняется такой скрипт `change-dns.sh`:

```
DNS_IP=`nslookup type=ns dns 2>/dev/null | grep "Server:" | head -n 1 | sed 's/Server:\s*//'`
echo -e "nameserver $DNS_IP\noptions timeout:2 rotate ndots:0" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Используется `nslookup`, а не`host` или `dig` по той причине, что эти программы не входят в состав BusyBox из образа alpine.

Конечно, хотелось бы решить эту проблему средствами `docker-compose.yml`